# IP address of Proximo add-on Heroku

Tags: heroku, proximo

How can I determine the IP address of Proximo add-on Heroku? I looked at the following link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

heroku config | grep PROXIMO_URL

PROXIMO_URL: http://proxy:password@proxy-12-34-45-56.proximo.io

so your ip address would be 12.34.45.56